# how does real-time image color filtering work

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, instagram

My current knowledge is that if I want to filter an image to, let's say, a bluish tint on a ppm image, I would loop through the RGB values and increase the blue values.

However, apps like Instagram have a slider that can be used to adjust the extent of the image filter. I would assume that the program doesn't keep looping through all the RGB values to modify them. So how is it achieved so quickly?

Comment: wrong. that's exactly what happens. except GPUs are faster at it. that's their purpose. also, your straight-forward loop code might not be as fast as it could be on a CPU. compiler might not see a way to optimize it (SIMD instructions and whatnot).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Is the GPU on the server side? If this is the case, then that would mean that every time I move the slider, I am sending a request to the server to tint my image, then the sever will send me new RGB values. This would mean that, for a 2MB image, I am downloading 2MB with every movement of the slider. If I'm wrong, kindly elaborate more

Comment: Modifying the values of the RGB components of, say, a 1K x 1K image takes like 1 ms on a modern CPU. In the old days, color palettes we used to map one-byte pixels to RGB, and it was enough to modify the palette rather than the pixels (256 entries, in a few microseconds). But this has many limitations.

Comment: As regards Web apps, the updates are not done on the server and downloaded, they are computed locally.

Comment: phones contain GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

This operation does not actually have much computational volume because the processors are high speed.

Of course, there is another way to do this, and that is to use the Fourier transform method. You can search about ((Filter in Frequency domain)) if you wish.

Comment: It’s a different type of filter that you can apply through the Fourier Transform. Computing a single FFT is way more expansive that what this color filter does.